# How to frame a polite sentence without using "please"? Is it even possible?

Tags: politeness

I am just wondering that, are there any alternatives to make a sentence look polite. Instead of using "please".

Kindly help me with examples.

Comment: If it's a request you might say "Would you do me the kindness to xxxx?"  But it requires a bit of sensitivity to not come off as sarcastic.  Another form is "Would you do me a favor and xxxx?"  (Ditto)

Comment: Yeah, that sounds good, but to me it looks a bit old fashioned. Sorry, I am just saying what I felt.

Comment: It is, but being polite is old-fashioned.

Comment: @HotLicks what's that supposed to mean? :/

Comment: You used "kindly" in place of "Please" and it certainly works.

Comment: My comment was on two levels.  First, society has slowly become less and less polite over the past 100-200 years.  Second, one can give statements an air of politeness by "sounding old-fashioned".

Comment: Unless you are by nature arrogant and conceited (I suspect not), politeness is all about feeling comfortable when talking to people. If you maintain a pleasant air, and just talk naturally you will come over as polite. Of course there are a number of expressions you can use to help, only one of which is *please*. *Would you be so kind as to...*, *Could I trouble you...* *Would you mind if I did so and so...* If you list these and practice introducing them into your speech you will find you are rewarded with smiles and charm.

Comment: Woah.. I think @HotLicks took it quite personally. I just said what I felt. Please let it go. And, I really appreciate everybody who took effort to answer my question. Thanks a lot :):D!!

Comment: Nothing to "let go" -- I was not offended in any way.  In a sense, politeness is about taking the time to consider the other person.  In modern times, with language increasingly spoken in smrtphn abbrev8ions, it's easy to forget this.

Answer (score 2):

Short along with being polite, ***Could you help me with examples?***

To be even more polite, you could say, ***Would you mind helping me with examples?***

Still polite but a bit "slacker," ***Do you mind helping me with examples?***

That all being said and depending on context, the most common way to politely solicit someone for help is, ***Can you help me with examples?***

Sounding polite is actually all about the **tone** you use.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

**Would you be so kind as to _____ ?** or **Would you be kind enough to ____ ?**

> Would you be so kind as to fill this out for me?
>
> Would you be kind enough to close the door?

(http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/would-you-be-kind-enough-to-do-something)

Note that this is very polite but also formal.

It also depends on the context. A granny talking to her grandson might say something like, **Would you be a dear and fetch my groceries?**

Answer (score 0):

Polite alternatives for: **Could you please give some examples?** and **Please could you give some examples?**

The questions in bold, I must add, are more idiomatic in British English than the OP's polite request: *Kindly help me with examples.* The term *kindly* is very old fashioned, and nowadays it typically sounds Indian English. Nothing wrong with that, I quite like that expression, it sounds charming but also a bit ‘quaint’.

I wouldn't recommend saying numbers 1 and 2 because you might come off as sounding sarcastic, or as the Brits might ask: *Are you taking the piss?* But they're examples of an era gone, when British people were apologetic to the point of absurdity. They're merely illustrative, and for me, good fun. On the other hand, examples 3 to 5 are fine for everyday occurrences.

> 1. I'm terribly sorry for bothering you, but would you be so kind as to provide me with a few examples?
> 2. I hope I'm not disturbing you, but I'd be delighted if you could provide me with a few examples.
> 3. May/Can I ask you a favour? Could/Can you give me a couple of examples? Thanks.
> 4. Is it all right if I ask you for some examples? Thanks.
> 5. Do us a favour would you? A couple of examples would be great. [Ta very much! (if speaking to a Londoner)]

Answer (score -1):

You've answered your own question, really. "Kindly help me with examples" works just as well as "Please help me with examples."

Comment: Both of these often come across as rather curt demand-requests rather than pure requests. Elian's hedged versions are more acceptable, though I'd throw in a 'please' as well.